# Pow function in C returns 0

Tags: c

Want to create a program that asks the user to input 2 numbers and output the first number to the power of the second one. Here is my code

```c
void func4()
{

    double f;
    double g;
    double result;
    printf("Enter first number:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &f);
    printf("Enter second number number:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &g);
    result = pow(f, g);
    printf("%f", result);
}
```

But when I put the numbers the output is always zero.

P.S. Libraries stdio.h and math.h are added in the header

Comment: `%f` is good, `%d` is bad. 2 seconds of effort to spot the bug. Your compiler should warn here. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: The `scanf` format for `double` is `%lf`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Format Specifiers [printf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)  & [scanf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: And seriously, what manner of sock puppet is up-voting "wrong format specifier question number 999 999 999 on SO"? We already have an endless number of questions like this. They are not interesting, they hold no value to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` format specifier is for reading `int`. You have to use proper specifier. You can use `%lf` for reading `double`.